# Arduino Keypad Library on NodeMCU buttons mapped the wrong way

Tags: arduino, nodemcu, keypad

I am attaching a 4x4 membrane keypad to my NodeMCU (ESP8266-12E).
I am using the standard Keypad library for Arduino.

The layout of the keypad look like this:

```
1 2 3 A
4 5 6 B
7 8 9 C
* 0 # D
```

Everything works fine except the buttons A and B, which will behave like the buttons 1 and 4, so Pressing A gives me 1, and pressing B gives me 4.

I tried testing the same code on a Arduino Nano, the problem doesn't occur here.
I also tested the Keypad itself to see if it was wired correctly. The keypad is wired correctly.

What is causing the keypad to not work on the buttons A and B?

The code:

```cpp
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {'1','2','3', 'A'},
    {'4','5','6', 'B'},
    {'7','8','9', 'C'},
    {'*','0','#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5,4,0,2};
byte colPins[COLS] = {14,12,13,15};


Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
byte ledPin = 13; 

boolean blink = false;
boolean ledPin_state;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);              // Sets the digital pin as output.
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);           // Turn the LED on.
    ledPin_state = digitalRead(ledPin);   // Store initial LED state. HIGH when LED is on.
    keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent); // Add an event listener for this keypad
}

void loop(){
    char key = keypad.getKey();

    if (key) {
        Serial.println(key);
    }
    if (blink){
        digitalWrite(ledPin,!digitalRead(ledPin));    // Change the ledPin from Hi2Lo or Lo2Hi.
        delay(100);
    }
}

// Taking care of some special events.
void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent key){
    switch (keypad.getState()){
    case PRESSED:
        if (key == '#') {
            digitalWrite(ledPin,!digitalRead(ledPin));
            ledPin_state = digitalRead(ledPin);        // Remember LED state, lit or unlit.
        }
        break;

    case RELEASED:
        if (key == '*') {
            digitalWrite(ledPin,ledPin_state);    // Restore LED state from before it started blinking.
            blink = false;
        }
        break;

    case HOLD:
        if (key == '*') {
            blink = true;    // Blink the LED when holding the * key.
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how did you wire the keypad to the NodeMCU? NodeMCU doesn't expose pins 6, 7 and 8. And pin 3 is the RX pin.

Comment: My bad, this was the code tested on the Arduino, the only thing changed was the pinout, i updated the code to use the NodeMCU pins instead

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be the use of pin D8.

If you shift all of your connectors to D0 - D7 you will find that this works as expected